# Is there a way to write a string to the end of the file without the append option?

Tags: c, linux, unix

Is there a way to open a file and write any string to the end of the file without using the `O_APPEND` (append) option when opening the file?

I'm coding in C in a Unix environment for the first time for class.

I know I could use `lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END)` to seek the end of the file and `fstat()` to get the file size, but overall, I'm not sure what my code should be like.

What i have is

```
int fwrite = open (“abc.txt”, O_RDWR);
int fread = open
```

Also, this is my first time on Stack Overflow, please guide me

Comment: `lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END)` should be enough, no need to involve `fstat`. Do you have code that creates a file descriptor?

Comment: no i don't, unfortunately i don't know how to :( i'm not sure where to begin actually, but here's what i have Int f_writeFile = open (“file.txt”, O_RDWR);
Int f_readFile = open. But how would I write a string to the end of the file?

Comment: Please edit that code into your question. Do you know how to write a string to the *beginning* of a file?

Comment: not sure how to write it to the beginning, without append option unfortunately

Comment: How would you do it *with* the append option?

Comment: with the append option, you would do: int main() {  
  FILE *out = fopen("filename", "a");  
  fprintf(out, "%s", "aString");  
  fclose(out);  
  return 0;  
}

Comment: You can use `O_RDWR` then read the entire file into memory (using `fread fscanf` etc) and then close the file, Then reopen the file and write the memory data into the file and add the data you want to write.

Comment: Your example code is perplexing at best. Incorrect quoting ensures it won't compile.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but no.  O_APPEND has a special attribute that permits multiple processes to write to the file in non-interfering mode.   So, if N independent processes open a file O_APPEND, the writes might be interleaved, but will be coherent.  This is exploited in log files as an example.

If you open the file, lseek to the end, by the time you write(), the end point might have changed and you are over-writing valid data.

In short, if you need to append, use O_APPEND; if you want random access don't.  The same program can open the same file in different modes.

Comment: Ah okay, that's what i was thinking actually, but my prof asked us to make this possible

Comment: A long dive into stupid mode could use mandatory file locking, but the whole file locking thing was less well thought out than, uh, I can't find a local minimum; so file locking is crap and should be avoided unless absolutely necessary!   There, a 30 year unix kernel dude spoke :_